# MySQL: update table column while formatting date format into other format not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am updating a table's date column field using DATE_FORMAT and STR_TO_DATE functions but that is not working at all. If I am using **DATE_FORMAT** then It's giving me an error,

> **Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-24T12:20:16+0000'**

Or if I am using **STR_TO_DATE** then it's giving me an error,

> **Error Code: 1411. Incorrect time value: 'T12:20:16+0000' for function str_to_date**

My Query is :

```
update quality
set analysedAt = DATE_FORMAT(analysedAt,'%Y-%m-%d %T')
where qualityId = 3;
```

Where anaylseAt = `2018-03-27T12:25:16+0000`
                                                .

Can someone please help me?

Comment: can show what is the current format of `analysedAt`. + some sample data

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go from a string to a *date*, then the function you should be using is `STR_TO_DATE`, not `DATE_FORMAT`, which goes in the opposite direction.  But you have a bigger problem, because it looks like the `analysedAt` column is text, and you won't be able to update it with a date necessarily.  Even if you could, through some implicit conversion, you would still be stuck with text again, defeating the whole purpose.

I propose adding a new datetime column, and then updating it:

```
UPDATE quality
SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(analysedAt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s');
```

Afterwards, you may drop the `analysedAt` column if you no longer need it:

```
ALTER TABLE quality DROP analysedAt;
```

There is a demo link below which shows that the above call to `STR_TO_DATE` does correctly capture the date and time portion of your timestamp.

### Demo